# Change Width of Dropdown Menu

Tags: html, css, button

I am using a bootstrap button for a small project. I've changed the color of the button from default blue to dark gray. Font is white. AFTER I click the button and remove the mouse from the button, the text color turns to a dark gray/black.

I've tried overriding the bootstrap stye with .btn:active but that doesn't seem to work. Any direction would be great.

[image: Dropdown Menu]

```
  <style>
    * {
       border-radius: 0 !important;
    }

    .btn{
      background-color: #282828 ;
      width: 250px;
      text-align: left;
      color: white;
    }

    .btn:hover {
      background-color: #282828 ;
      color: white;
    }

    .btn:active {
      color: white !important;
    }

    .caret {
      float: right;
    }

    .dropdown-menu {
    width: 250px;
    }

   .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
    position: relative;
    background: #51aecc;
    color: white;
}

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-custom dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Select Language
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Romania</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Espana</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">United States</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Deutschland</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nederland</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle? you don't have complete html here

Comment: I got the code from here: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_comp_dropdown-menu&stacked=h.  Not really sure how to incorporate this with a fiddle. I don't have any of the JS code since its sourced.  I could be wrong though? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Got you covered with an answer below :)

Comment: Ahhh awesome! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The style you want to override is:

```
.btn:focus{
   color: #FFF
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rvzd7rtq/